# How to obtain increment order id in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm new to magento, and I'm just trying to log the increment id number of an order. I can get the log to show up, but it's only the last order placed. I want it to be order specific. Here's what I'm currently using in my controller.

```
$last_order_increment_id = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getIncrementId();

        Mage::log('Email sent for order number ' . $last_order_increment_id, null , 'system.log');
```

Comment: Do you want to get order during checkout process or at what stage or just want order id could you please clear with this ?

Comment: I just want the order id. This is a separate from the checkout, it's an order history page that users can see their order history. There's a link that a customer can click on that will eventually trigger an email based on a certain order, but for now, I just want to log it to make sure I'm getting the order number.

Comment: Okay so you want to log order number when corresponding link will click and it should be user specific to make sure whether email send or not am I right ?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect. Its should be create a log file in magento/var/log/ directory.

By default, Magento does not register messages about errors and exceptions; so if something bad happens, you don't even know.

When you want to create log file in your system, you need to enable log setting in your system.

To turn on the logging, you can navigate to **System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Log Settings** and set the **Enabled** option to **Yes**

> Don't forget to set full access permissions (777) to the following folder: /var/log, since that is the place where those log files are stored.

Then execute your script.